# How to Create Web Deploy Package for Sitecore Modules

Tags: azure, data-exchange-framework, paas

We are currently using Sitecore PaaS implementation for Sitecore 9 Update 1 and would like to know if it is possible to create a Web Deploy Package for other Sitecore Modules like Data Exchange Framework. Is there a better approach on doing this as the latest DEF have several modules in it.

I have found this [blogpost](http://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-on-azure-create-custom-web-deploy-packages-using-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit/) in which I will try and just like to get some thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this.
Navigate to your Sitecore Azure Toolkit path in Powershell and run the following after unblocking all the files.

- Import-Module .\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1
- Import-Module .\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll

[image]

And now we can use the commands to create the WDP for the Sitecore Module like Data Exchange Framework by running this command.

ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "C:\Sc DEF Packages for Sc9U1\Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108.zip" -Destination "C:\WDP"

After the script run you can inspect the scwdp.zip file generated and check if it already contains the dacpac and the other contents of the module.
[image]

Everything is now set and create your azuredeploy.json for this package and update your azuredeploy.parameters.json to add this in the modules node item.

Comment: Do you have an example on installing this newly created scwdp?

Answer (score 0):

One more important point (inputs from @Mohammad Abujaffal), if we unblock the DLL then only you can import the DLL's.